# DJANGO - How to display multiple database rows in one row in view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working with a 1-N relationship (1 ticket has N messages), in the admin view I'm trying to pull things from the database, but the N msg's related to ticket X, are coming as N lines (one line for each msg from ticket X) in the view (I display it in a table), I need the N messages to be passed in one line only, below is an example of how this is happening and how I need it to be.

Current output:

```
| Ticket id | Msg id  |      Content      | Status |
|:---------:|:-------:|:-----------------:|:------:|
| 1         |  1      | msg 1 of ticket 1 |  Open  |
| 2         |  2      | msg 1 of ticket 2 | Closed |
| 2         |  3      | msg 2 of ticket 2 | Closed |
| 3         |  4      | ticket 3 - msg 1  |  Open  |
| 4         |  5      | msg 1 of ticket 2 | Closed |
| 3         |  6      | ticket 3 - msg 2  |  Open  |
```

How I need it to be:

```
| Ticket id | Msg id  |                Content               | Status |
|:---------:|:-------:|:------------------------------------:|:------:|
| 1         |  1      | msg 1 of ticket 1                    |  Open  |
| 2         |  2      | msg 1 of ticket 2; msg 2 of ticket 2 | Closed |
| 3         |  4      | ticket 3 - msg 1; ticket 3 - msg 2   |  Open  |
| 4         |  5      | msg 1 of ticket 2                    | Closed |
```

For example in my detail view of each ticket I managed to do what I wanted above, but in this case I only pull ticket X and its messages, now that I pull everything from the bank I don't know how to do it

My detail view of each ticket:

```
def ticket_by_id(request, ticket_id):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
    mesTicket = MessageTicket.objects.filter(fk_ticket=ticket_id)
    aux = ''
    for itens in mesTicket:
        aux += str(itens.content) + '; '
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is Postgres, you can aggregate with [StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) or [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg). Probably something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.db.models import Min

messages = MessageTicket.objects\
    .values('ticket_id', 'status')\
    .annotate(
        agg_content=StringAgg('content', ','),
        min_msg_id=Min('msg_id'))
```

or

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import Min

messages = MessageTicket.objects\
    .values('ticket_id', 'status')\
    .annotate(
        agg_content=ArrayAgg('content'),
        min_msg_id=Min('msg_id'))
```

If you cannot use DB aggregation, you can do that in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) with only a couple lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
messages = MessageTicket.objects.values('ticket_id', 'msg_id', 'content', 'status')
df = pd.DataFrame(messages)
agg_messages = df.groupby(['ticket_id', 'status']).agg({'msg_id': min, 'content': list})
print(agg_messages.reset_index().to_dict('records'))
```

Comment: @ Borut, thanks for the idea, I'm using sqlite, but I'll try to apply something with this line of reasoning, thanks for your attention, I'll come back here to give the feedback how useful your tip was, thanks

Comment: @Pedro-Maho SQlite doesn't have many aggregate functions built-in, so this approach definitely won't work. I guess you'll have to do aggregation in the code. I can add an example how to do it with pandas.

Comment: @ Borut I saw your comment, but I was away for the weekend, thanks again, and as you said sqllite doesn't have as many aggregation functions, but I managed to solve it...
I received all the tickets and all the messages, I saved the tickets in a list (because I couldn't work with the query set), I made a loop and added a list with the messages that had the id equal to the id of the ticket inside the list of tickets, and in the html I went through this list within the list displaying it in a <Li>

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this:

Query from the bank (query set)

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.order_by('id')[:]
mesTickets = MessageTicket.objects.order_by('id')[:]
array = [] # list array auxiliar
```

For each ticket in 'tickets' I created a new 'msg' field and allocated ticket in array

```
for i in tickets: 
    i.msg = []
    array.append(i)
```

For each msg in 'mesTickets' I confirmed if the msg.id was equal to the ticket.id, if so, I assigned the msgs in the list 'msg' inside the list 'array'

```
{% for i in array %}
     <tr>
          <td>{{i.id}}</td>
          <td>
              <ul>
                  {% for j in i.msg %}
                      <li>{{j.content}}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```